# Magento 2.2.2 - After update cart error has occurred :We can't find the quote item

Tags: cart, magento2.2.2

After editing a product, i get this error,

> We can't find the quote item.

I cannot get new quote_id after editing a product.

Has anyone got any idea about this?

Comment: did u find any solution to this?

Comment: @Zinat No. I can't.

Comment: I found the reason, do you know it too?

Comment: No. I do not know it.

Comment: so the reason is "\Magento\Checkout\Model\Layout\DepersonalizePlugin". It checks if page requires 'de-personalization'( blocks are cacheable and cache is enabled) it clears the checkoutSessions' storage.

Comment: But having cacheable="false" is not solution in my opinion. Please let me know if you found another solution. Tnx

Comment: I know that why this does not work. because of whenever I edit cart item and click on `update cart` then this error occurred.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78285/discussion-between-dhaduk-mitesh-and-zinat).

Comment: @DhadukMitesh did you solve this issue?

Comment: @RendyEkoPrastiyo Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please create/update this file.

```
Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js
```

Code:

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Msrp/js/msrp': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/msrp': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Create a new file in `Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/msrp.js`

Code:

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {
    return function (originalWidget) {
        $.widget('mage.addToCart', $.mage.sidebar,
        {
            _addToCartSubmit: function (event) {
                this.element.trigger('addToCart', this.element);

                if (this.element.data('stop-processing')) {
                    return false;
                }

                if (this.options.addToCartButton) {
                    $(this.options.addToCartButton).click();

                    return false;
                }

                if (this.options.addToCartUrl) {
                    $('.mage-dropdown-dialog > .ui-dialog-content').dropdownDialog('close');
                }
                event.preventDefault();
                $(this.options.cartForm).submit();
            }
        }
        );
        return $.mage.addToCart;
    };
});
```

Execute the below command.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Now check it and it is working properly.